# Display Non-Zero Return Status in PS1

Tags: bash, prompt

I want to include the return status in my prompt. (Easy add `'$? '`, right?)

However, I only want the status returned (and trailing space) if non-zero.

Example:

```
sd ~ $ false
1 sd ~ $ true
sd ~ $
```

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5946873/3821804

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the `promptvars` option is on (it is by default). Then put whatever code you like in `PROMPT_COMMAND` to define a variable containing exactly what you want in the prompt.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_status="$? "; if [[ $prompt_status == "0 " ]]; then prompt_status=; fi'
PS1='$prompt_status\h \w \$ '
```

In zsh you could use its conditional construct in `PS1` (bash has no equivalent).

```
PS1='%(?,,%? )%m %~ %# '
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not required to use `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Here it does needless complications. All you have to do is define this function:

```
prompt_status()
{
    [ $? = 0 ] && return
    echo -n "${?} "
}
```

And then set PS1 like this:

```
shopt -s promptvars
PS1='$(prompt_status)'$PS1
```

Evaluation of `prompt_status()` inside subshell protects `$?` from being changed.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can have is obtained by

```
PS1='${?/#0/}'":$PS1"
```

where I added a `:` as a separator, so not exactly what is in the question.